# How to set a timer before a sound file starts playing in VBScript (MsgBox)?

Tags: windows, vbscript

Is it possible to set a timer before starting to play an audio file in VBScript? I need the sound signal to be played not immediately, but after a certain time. But the rest of the script started immediately.

*Here's my script*:

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.URL = "\to\path"
Sound.Controls.play
MsgBox "msg", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + 262144, "title"
```

Comment: with `set a timer` do you mean *wait x seconds*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729075/how-to-set-delay-in-vbscript

Comment: Not a timer, but you can use sleep. `wscript.sleep 1000` where 1000 is 1s in ms

Comment: I need the sound signal to be played not immediately, but after a certain time. But the rest of the script started immediately.

Comment: For asynchronous execution, you have two choices 1) break the script into two files with one file containing a WScript.Sleep delay followed by the code to play the sound and use the Run method to start that from that main script with bWaitOnReturn set to false, 2) Convert the script to an HTA and use window.SetTimeout to play the sound after a certain wait time, while the rest of the code continues to run.

Comment: Note that for (1) you can still have a single VBS file. It would just have to generate the second script in the Temp folder before running it.